# Probability on human pyramid

Tags: probability

To obtain a gold coin, 6 men, all of different weight, are trying to build a human pyramid: three men at the bottom, two men on top of these men and the remaining man on top of these two men. The human pyramid is called "stable" if anyone not in the bottom row is supported by each of the two closest people beneath him and no body can be supported by anybody of lower weight. Formation of a stable pyramid is the only condition to get a gold coin. What is the probability that they will get the gold coin?

Comment: Success configurations are 

1. $x_1|x_2x_3|x_4x_5x_6$ with permutations on each level to obtain a unique pyramid.

2. $x_1|x_2x_4|x_3x_5x_6$ and $x_1|x_2x_4|x_3x_6x_5$.

Comment: This is more a puzzle than a question about probability. Find the number of stable constructions and divide by the total number of constructions. It would not surprise me if you allready had that idea.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the pyramid to be a success, the person on top must have the lowest weight. On the second level, either the people with the second and third lowest weight are selected, or the people with the second and fourth lowest are selected while the person with the third lowest weight is only below the person with the second lowest weight. The number of valid pyramids thus equals:

$$1! \cdot (2! \cdot 3! + 2! \cdot 2!) = 12 + 4 = 16$$

As such, the probability of getting the gold coin equals:

$$\frac{16}{6!} = \frac{16}{720} = \frac{1}{45} \approx 0.0222$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the $6$ men have the weights (in $20$kg): $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

All possible pyramids: $P_6^6=6!=720$.

All possible stable pyramids: $$(\{1\},\{2,3\},\underbrace{\{4,5,6\}}_{=P_3^3})+(\{1\},\{3,2\},\underbrace{\{4,5,6\}}_{=P_3^3})+$$
$$(\{1\},\{2,4\},\{3,\underbrace{5,6}_{P_2^2}\})+(\{1\},\{4,2\},\{\underbrace{5,6}_{P_2^2},3\})=16.$$
Thus:
$$P(stable)=\frac{n(stable)}{N}=\frac{16}{720}=\frac{1}{45}.$$